# Program for counting days

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I need a program to count days, from day 1 to day 21 for my project.

I'm making an artificial incubator and I need to show the days on an LCD.

Comment: Don't shout, use punctuation to start with. What part you need help with? Counting days in what sense? (with a for loop, or using a real time clock?) Be more precise in your requirements. What do you mean with 'like so' ?

Comment: google: "DS3231 Arduino". DS3231 is an Real Time Clock module which allows you to keep track of time and date.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be very accurate, you can use `millis()`

Comment: For what it's worth, one day is just 86400000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily using Real Time Clock IC. ds1307/ds3231 ic will do the job. Adafruit has Arduino library for that. easy to interface.

I don't supprt using millis() function. you will lose your time if the system power downs or mcu resets. Using RTC chip is safe option as it has backup battery for time keeping.